# how to find the textbox value changed by setting val() function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to Implement an **New AutoComplete Control**. I have an textbox `$("#Code")`. When the values has been selected from the table I am assigning the selected value using

```
$("#Code").val(selectedValue);
```

Since I have to check the validation for the same I am trying to get the change event of the text box `$("#Code")`. The same is firing when I keypress on the textbox but the change event not firing when I assign using `$.val()` function.

I have tried the following.

```
Entity="#Code"; //for example

 $(Entity).keypress(function (event) {
   firing on keypress.. // ok.. No Problem
 });

 $(Entity).keydown(function (event) {
   firing on keydown.. // ok.. No Problem
 });

 $(Entity).bind('input',function() {
   firing on keypress.. // ok.. No Problem
 });

 $(Entity).change(function (event) {
   firing on keypress.. // ok.. No Problem
 });
```

Could anyone please help how to detect the event of `val()`?

Comment: Setting the value programmatically isn't supposed to fire those events, but you can do `$("#Code").val(selectedValue).change()` to call the change handler yourself right after setting the value...

Comment: Too bad that wasn't posted as an answer so it could be "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call change method explicitly

```
$("#ID").val("hi").change();
```

Thanks